# Why ArrayList<String> get() returns Object not String in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, generic-type-argument

While making an argument parser, I used `ArrayList<String>`.
[Refering to this official Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), `ArrayList<E>.get()` should be returning `E` typed Objects, so `ArrayList<String>.get()` should be returning `String` Objects.

However, I am getting Object instead of String elements in this case.

[image]

```java
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Data
public class Argument<T> {
    public ArrayList<String> Args;
    public String Description;
    public Boolean Required;
    public Boolean HasValue;
    public T Value;
}
```

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArgumentParser {
    private ArrayList<Argument> argumentList_;

    public String ArgList() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        for (Argument argument : argumentList_) {

            //Here is the problem
            for (String arg : argument.Args) {
                builder.append(arg);
                builder.append(", ");
            }
        }
        //Delete Traling Comma
        builder.delete(builder.length());
        builder.delete(builder.length());

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Is this situation

1. A bug in IDE Environment (IntelliJ + Lombok)
2. My code is making Java do this (Generic Typing)

Help me...

Comment: What is the exact compilation error you're getting, if any? Note you're using the raw type of `Argument` inside your `ArgumentParser` class.

Comment: What leads you to believe you're getting an Object rather than a String? Please add any errors or proof.

Comment: Show your log  please

Comment: Also, please follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), at least when posting to a public forum. It makes it easier to read your code and allows Stack Overflow to apply the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: Pay attention to the warnings you have.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks. I was programming with C++ and Google C++ Style Guide (and so used to it) so I didn't know that resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first piece of code `Argument` is defined to have a type parameter.

```
public class Argument<T> {
    public ArrayList<String> Args;
```

In the second piece of code `Argument` is used but the type argument is missing.

```
    private ArrayList<Argument> argumentList_;
    // ...
        for (Argument argument : argumentList_) {
```

`ArrayList<Argument>` is a *rare* type (less frequently(?) known as a *partial raw type* - a type with a raw type argument). The behaviour of which is odd.

The easy fix is a wildcard.

```
    private ArrayList<Argument<?>> argumentList_;
    // ...
        for (Argument<?> argument : argumentList_) {
```

Comment: Called a *raw* type, not a *rare* type. [JLS 4.8. Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

Comment: @Andreas Clarified to say `ArrayList<Argument>` is a *rare type* (as non-normative part of JLS 4.8). Original didn't quote the second line (doesn't appear in history under the five minute rule).

Comment: Huh? Still not a *rare* type. It's called a ***raw*** type. --- And it's `Argument` that is *raw*, i.e. the culprit.

Comment: @Andreas `ArrayList<Argument` is certainly not a raw type. See your own citation for what 'rare' means. Tom is perfectly correct here.

Comment: @user207421 I never said that `ArrayList<Argument>` is a *raw* type. I said that `Argument`, which is without `<>` generic parameter types, is a *raw* type.